# Why this method does not get optimized away?

Tags: java, guava, compiler-optimization

This [Java method](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-tests/test/com/google/common/collect/CollectionBenchmarkSampleData.java#147) gets used in benchmarks for simulating slow computation:

```
static int slowItDown() {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        result += i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is IMHO a very bad idea, as its body can get replaced by `return 500500`. *This seems to never happen<sup>1</sup>*; probably because of such an optimization being irrelevant for real code as Jon Skeet stated.

Interestingly, a slightly simpler method with `result += 1;` gets fully optimized away (caliper reports 0.460543 ns).

But even when we agree that optimizing away methods returning a constant result is useless for real code, there's still loop unrolling, which could lead to something like

```
static int slowItDown() {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i += 2) {
        result += 2 * i + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

So my question remains: Why is no optimization performed here?

<sup>1</sup>Contrary to what I wrote originally; I must have seen something what wasn't there.

Comment: How did you test this? If using the JIT you'll probably observe similar things by slightly changing the code, since there are lots of heuristics involved. You're no way guaranteed for the JIT to apply even the simplest optimizations like inlining as it only does so once deemed necessary.

Comment: Is this real code? If you know what it's meant to return, why not just write the code that way? I'm content that JIT compilers are tuned to optimize *real* code rather than optimizing away code which wouldn't occur in reality. (Static optimizers have a bit more leeway than this, but remember that every optimization a JIT compiler tries to find has a cost at execution time*.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I observe, embarrassingly, that the link directs to Guava benchmarking code, which I would normally hope to trust...

Comment: return x + super.compareTo(e) - x; // silly attempt to prevent optimization.

So they seem to be aware at least :)

Comment: *How did you test this?* Using [caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper), so I'd trust the result. *Is this real code?* As I wrote, it's used to simulate a slow operation (e.g. `equals`). I agree that optimizing non-sense does not make much sense. @Louis Wasserman: It looks like nobody really cares about SlowElement, moreover it looks like it works, but it can stop working anytime.

Comment: `slowItDown` taken alone takes 300ns on my machine (using jmh), which is more or less the time I'd expect for 2000 additions + some comparisons. So it does not get optimised away. Checking the assembly shows a lot of loop unrolling but that's it (hotpost jdk 7u25). What JVM are you using?

Comment: @assylias: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode) from Oracle on a Core i5. Maybe jmh doesn't do enough warm-up? Or maybe I did something wrong? I'm going to re-run it.

Comment: @maaartinus jmh does enough warmup.

Comment: @araknoid: There's no problem and the question is in the title.

Comment: @maaartinus FYI, results of the tests in the class comment: https://bitbucket.org/assylias/performance/src/168b826c69e3998dde3ee44919a3b4ac26ef2839/src/main/java/com/assylias/performance/SO18667440.java?at=master (after 6 seconds of warmup) - Now admittedly that method is quite fragile (it could well be optimised by some JVMs) and they should have introduced some randomness if the delay really is required.

Comment: @assylias: I can not reproduce the case of the method being optimized away! I'll give it one more try before I rewrite the question.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Well if the purpose of the code is simply to slow things down, then clearly an "optimization" like this would be counterproductive. So I guess the question should be "Is there real code where you'd really want this to be optimized away?" If the answer is "no" then I see no reason why you'd want the JIT to spend time trying to spot this.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the JVM *does* optimize away such code. The question is how many times it has to be detected as a real hotspot (benchmarks do some more than this single method, usually) before it will be analyzed this way. In my setup it required 16830 invocations before the execution time went to (almost) zero.

It’s correct that such a code does not appear in real code. However it might remain after several inlining operations of other hotspots dealing with values not being compiling-time constants but runtime constants or de-facto constants (values that could change in theory but don’t practically). When such a piece of code remains it’s a great benefit to optimize it away entirely but that is not expected to happen soon, i.e. when calling right from the main method.

Update: I simplified the code and the optimization came even earlier.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final int inner=10;
  final float innerFrac=1f/inner;
  int count=0; 
  for(int j=0; j<Integer.MAX_VALUE; j++) {
    long t0=System.nanoTime();
    for(int i=0; i<inner; i++) slowItDown();
    long t1=System.nanoTime();
    count+=inner;
    final float dt = (t1-t0)*innerFrac;
    System.out.printf("execution time: %.0f ns%n", dt);
    if(dt<10) break;
  }
  System.out.println("after "+count+" invocations");
  System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
  System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));
}
static int slowItDown() {
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
      result += i;
  }
  return result;
}
```

…

```
execution time: 0 ns
after 15300 invocations
1.7.0_13
23.7-b01
```

(64Bit Server VM)

Comment: Could you kindly post you code? I'm curious how it happened that it all got optimized away - a I wrote I thought it happened to me too, but now I think I was seeing something what wasn't there.

Comment: It looks like the method gets optimized *away* rather than optimized (i.e., folded to a constant). I tried something like `x += slowItDown()` and print `x` at the end and the time went never below 300 ns. This corresponds with what you wrote; it's just that I was more curious about the folding (as this would destroy the benchmark I took the method from).